# Derivative of function of vector

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

$X$ is $n \times n$ symmetric matrix (constants), $y$ is $n \times 1$ vector.

What is the first derivative / differential of

$$f(y)=\exp(-\frac{1}{2}y'Xy) $$

Comment: what is the gradient of $  -\frac{1}{2}y'Xy  $

Comment: As a general rule you should first attempt to write out the differential, then see if you can separate something from it as the derivative.

Comment: Use the comment of @Will Jagy : you have a composition of two functions : the first one from $\mathbb{R^n}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ with maps $y \in \mathbb{R^n}$ to $z=-\frac{1}{2}y'Xy \in \mathbb{R}$ and the second one (the exponential map) that maps $z$ to $exp(z)$. Thus the derivative of this composition is a product of derivatives: the **row vector** $-y'X$ and the derivative of exp which is the function $exp$ itself as is well known.

Comment: So the derivative is the product of the derivative of $y'X$ and the exponential function?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the scalar variable
$$\eqalign{
 s &= X:yy^T \cr
}$$and its differential
$$\eqalign{
ds &= X:(dy\,y^T+y\,dy^T) \cr
   &= (Xy+X^Ty):dy \cr
   &= 2\,Xy:dy \cr
}$$
where colon denotes the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product.

Write the function in terms of this new variable. Now finding the differential and gradient is simple
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \exp(-s/2) \cr
\cr
df &= -\frac{1}{2}f\,ds \cr
   &= -f\,Xy:dy \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= -f\,Xy \cr
}$$